# error 4082 structure of query does not match function result type

Tags: sql, postgresql

im new in postgre and im trying to write stored procedure with the following code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_month_status()
returns table (request_detail character varying, request_detail2 character 
varying, request_detail3 character varying)
language plpgsql stable
as $function$
        BEGIN       
        return query

            select
            CASE
                WHEN (extract(DAY FROM now()) >= 25) THEN (extract(MONTH FROM now()) || '-' || extract(Year FROM now()))
                ELSE (extract(MONTH FROM now()) - 1 || '-' || extract(Year FROM now()))
            end,
            CASE
                WHEN (extract(month FROM now()) = 2) THEN (extract(month FROM now()) -1 || '-' || extract(Year FROM now()))
                ELSE (extract(month FROM now()) || '-' || extract(Year FROM now()))
            end,
            CASE
                WHEN (extract(month FROM now()) = 1) THEN (extract(month FROM now() - interval '2 months' ) || '-' || extract(Year FROM now()) -1)
                ELSE (extract(month FROM now()) || '-' || extract(Year FROM now()))
            end;
            end;
    $function$;
```

but whenever i tried to execute the commmand using `select * from get_month_status()` but i got an error saying

```
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
Detail: Returned type text does not match expected type character varying in column 1.
Where: PL/pgSQL function get_month_status() line 3 at RETURN QUERY
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: structure of query does not match 
function result type
Detail: Returned type text does not match expected type character varying in column 1.
Where: PL/pgSQL function get_month_status() line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

how do i make it work? someone help!

Answer (score 1):

Error message says what is wrong:

> Returned type text does not match expected type character varying

just change returned table's column types to `text` and recreate function

```
... returns table (request_detail text, request_detail2 text, request_detail3 text) ...
```